# Azure Notifications in PHP to single Users

Tags: php, azure, push-notification

I want to send Push Notifications from Azure using PHP to a single user. I'm already doing it to "All Users" registered in my cloud but I cant find the code (in PHP) that allow me to Push IT to one in espesific.

This is the (simple) code that I use to send to multiple Users, I guess it could be something similar:

```
include "NotificationHub.php";
$connection = "Endpoint=sb:......";
$hub = new NotificationHub($connection, "appetito24hub");
$notification = new Notification("apple", '{"aps":{"alert":{"title":"Estado de la orden", "body":"Tu orden ha cambiado del estado Aceptada a Procesada"}, "id":"4500", "type":"promo"}}');
$hub->sendNotification($notification);
```

Any Idea? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, and after checking the absurdly incomplete documentation of Microsoft Azure Notifications, I realize (after reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223266.aspx)) that you can add the "ServiceBusNotification-Tags" to the header so the notification can be sent to THAT espesific ID.

The real change was in the NotificationHup.php (if you downloaded the [Sample Code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/notificationhubs-rest-php) Provided by Azure Team) from this:

```
        $headers = [
        'Authorization: '.$token,
        'Content-Type: '.$contentType,
        'ServiceBusNotification-Format: '.$notification->format
        ];
```

to

```
    $headers = [
        'Authorization: '.$token,
        'Content-Type: '.$contentType,
        'ServiceBusNotification-Tags: '.$userTag,
        'ServiceBusNotification-Format: '.$notification->format
    ];
```

After that, everything worked just perfect.

Comment: what are the requirements to implement this push notif?