# How to Send Push Notification to a specific user on Notification Hub?

Tags: php, ios, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Is there any way where I can send a notification to a specific user? I tried to use the deviceToken. But I couldn't find any tutorial that shows a way where I can send notifications to a devicetoken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the description on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#push-user:

> When an authenticated user registers for push notifications, a user ID tag is automatically added to the registration. By using this tag, you can send push notifications to all devices registered by a specific user.

You can create an EasyTable script associate to a table to store your authenticated user's ID. You can leverage following code snippet to implement this:

```
table.insert(function (context) {
    context.item.userId = context.user.id;
    return context.execute();
});
```

Refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk.md#how-to-adjust-the-query-that-is-used-with-table-operations for more.

Then use this [PHP sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/notificationhubs-rest-php) to send notification with the user id:

```
$hub = new NotificationHub("<connectionString>", "<hubName>");
$message = '{"data":{"message":"Hello from PHP!"}}';
$notification = new Notification("gcm", $message);
$hub->sendNotification($notification, "_UserId:sid:<UserId>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have a device token to send the push. There are several ways to obtain the device token. The following example will help you.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [tags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx). Associate a unique tag with each user and then send a notification to that tag.

[Azure Notification Hubs Notify Users for iOS with .NET backend](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-ios-apple-apns-notification/) is a step-by-step tutorial which gives you an idea of how to work with tags.

And [How to use Notification Hubs from PHP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-php-push-notification-tutorial/) will give you and idea of how to do that in PHP.

Also, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32340572/182371) and [the sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/notificationhubs-rest-php) it refers to.

Once you have a prototype ready, use [Diagnosis guidelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer/) to troubleshoot any issues.

Comment: The problem is im  trying to store tags but nothing happens in the Azure Portal. Here is the object im sending `[NSSet setWithObjects:@"user", nil];`.

Comment: Oh, Notification Hubs tags are different from Azure Resource Manager tags you see in Azure Portal. It's really confusing, see if [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38534891/182371) to [Why are Azure Notification Hub tags not saving?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335644/why-are-azure-notification-hub-tags-not-saving/38534891#38534891) clarifies it. Also take a look at [Debugging Notification Hubs using Service Bus Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530751.aspx#sb_explorer).